# jquery, jsf integration does not work..!

Tags: jquery, jsf, modal-dialog

I am supposed to load a div into a modal dialog on click ok a link. but it does not work here is code, can some one help.

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<h:head>

    <script src="JqueryLib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="application_1.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jquery-ui.css"></h:outputStylesheet>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#viewDetails").click(function(){

$("#popup").dialog({
     modal: true,
    height: 400,
    width:600,
     buttons: {
     Ok: function() {
     $( this ).dialog( "close" );} }
});



})    
});
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="title">my title</ui:define>



            <ui:define name="content">

                <div class="content2">

                    <div class="tabs">

                        <h1>Overview</h1>

                            <p>
                                test test
                            </p>

                        <f:view>

                            <h:form id="testForm">

                            <h:outputLink id="viewDetails" value="#">
                <h:outputText value="View Details"/>
            </h:outputLink>



            <h:panelGroup id="popup" class="popup" title="test Panel" layout="block" >

            </h:panelGroup>


                            </h:form>

                        </f:view>



                    </div>

                </div>

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

</h:body>

</ui:composition>
```

Not sure what is wrong here, when I click on the link it is supposed to show the dialog box , if i test it with a simple jsf page works fine, but not this page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
...
<script src="JqueryLib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

You're loading and mixing 4 different jQuery files. This will of course fail because they will conflict with each other. You should have and use only one jQuery file. I recommend to stick to RichFaces-bundled one. Get rid of all those `<script>` references to jQuery.

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

If you can't guarantee if your current page would use RichFaces ajaxified components, for which RichFaces-bundled jQuery will be automatically loaded, then you can force its loading by

```
<ui:composition ... xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
...
<h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />
```

Note that you do **not** need to provide your own file. The `<h:outputScript>` will automatically load it from the RichFaces JAR file.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, RichFaces has a [`<rich:popupPanel>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky) out the box. Have you looked at it instead of homegrowing it?

Comment: Thanks for reply but we dont use rich faces even though It was sitting there

Comment: Then uninstall RichFaces (to avoid potential jQuery conflicts) and provide ONE jQuery file instead of three.